# PyCharm can't create a Conda environment because of a bash error

Tags: python, pycharm

I just purchased PyCharm. I'm trying to create a new project with a Conda environment. PyCharm, while advertising support for this, appears to have some flaws that prevent it even from creating the environment:

After selecting `Conda` as the virtual environment, PyCharm makes an attempt to install the dependent packages. But them it explodes with a serious error and says the packages were rolled back:

```
No such file or directory: 'bin/bash'
```

I'm using `zsh` on a Macbook Pro, Mac OS version 10.15.7.

What is even more disturbing is this:

```
(base) ➜  ~ which bash
/bin/bash
```

So, `bash` is right there in `/bin/bash`. It seems like this is a very bad error, and it makes the software completely unusable.

The Conda command that PyCharm is trying and failing to run is this:

```
conda create -p <my_conda_path>/envs/week1_python -y python=3.7
```

Please note that that command runs perfectly at the command line, outside the confines of PyCharm. So this is definitely the fault of PyCharm, not Conda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a comment more than an answer, but for some reason, PyCharm is looking for `bin/bash` and not `/bin/bash`.